# How to open a new shell and run a command on it?

Tags: python, bash

I want to run a code which opens a new shell and run the following command on it.

I tried those lines:

```
cmd_line = "env > help.txt"
subprocess.Popen(cmd_line, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                 stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

But its not opening a new shell.

Comment: Why are you expecting that it will spawn a shell. The above action will run the **cmd_line** in background and boom terminates.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) method does not spawn a new instance of the shell. From the docs:

> Execute a child program in a new process. On POSIX, the class uses os.execvp()-like behavior to execute the child program. On Windows, the class uses the Windows CreateProcess() function. The arguments to Popen are as follows.

The `shell` keyword argument does not open up a new shell for you, it runs the process under a new shell in the background before closing it. By default the she is `sh`

> On POSIX with shell=True, the shell defaults to /bin/sh. If args is a string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell. This means that the string must be formatted exactly as it would be when typed at the shell prompt. This includes, for example, quoting or backslash escaping filenames with spaces in them. If args is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell itself. That is to say, Popen does the equivalent of: `Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', args[0], args[1], ...])`

Under the hood python is "opening" a new shell, but it is hidden in the background and never shown explicitly to the user.
If you were looking to open a new shell for the user to interact with, you'd want to run the shell, and wait for it to terminate.

```
child_shell = Popen("/usr/bin/sh")

child_shell.wait()
```